# ¿Por que mis métodos no funcionan?

Tags: java

Cuando creo un método en el outline aparece un cuadrado rojo y no funciona, además en la declaración del método el nombre del método no se pone en cursiva. Son métodos muy simples restar, sumar,... y los he hasta copiado y es como si no tuviera el código.  No se que hago mal. Por favor ¿Alguien sabe a que se puede deber y como solucionarlo?

```
package funciones;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ejercicio2 {

    public Ejercicio2() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        
        Scanner leer=new Scanner (System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Introduce un número");
        int num1=leer.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Introduce el segundo número");
        int num2=leer.nextInt();
        int cambio = 0;
        int MayorxMenor=intercambio(num1, num2, cambio);
        int res=resta(num1,num2);
        
    }

    private int resta(int num1, int num2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int res;
        res=num1-num2;
        return res;
    }
    

    private int intercambio(int num1, int num2, int cambio) {
        if (num1<num2) {
            cambio=num1;
            num1=num2;
            num2=num1;
        
    }
        return num1;

    
    }

}
```

Comment: Donde esta el método main?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 4):

El problema es que no tienes un método main() que sería el punto de entrada de tu aplicación, el punto donde iniciaría la ejecución de tu aplicación.

El el método `Ejercicio2()` que usas, es el constructor de tu clase y debería usarse para únicamente inicializar tu aplicación:

```
public class Ejercicio2 {

    //Constructor.
    public Ejercicio2() {
       ...
      ...
    }
    //Metodo main()
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      ...
      ...
    }

}
```

Debes realizar el cambio agregando primeramente tu método `main(String[] args)`  ahí agregar la lógica principal, como este es static, para poder referenciar los métodos `resta()` e `intercambio()`, debes usar el modificador `static`:

```
package funciones;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ejercicio2 {

    public Ejercicio2() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner leer=new Scanner (System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Introduce un número");
        int num1=leer.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Introduce el segundo número");
        int num2=leer.nextInt();
        int cambio = 0;
        int MayorxMenor=intercambio(num1, num2, cambio);
        int res=resta(num1,num2);
        System.out.println("resta: " +res);
    }

    private static int resta(int num1, int num2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int res;
        res=num1-num2;
        return res;
    }
    

    private static int intercambio(int num1, int num2, int cambio) {
        if (num1<num2) {
            cambio=num1;
            num1=num2;
            num2=num1;        
        }
        return num1;
    }

}
```